# Set default text style when using AlertDialog.Builder.setCustomTitle()

Tags: android-layout, android, android-styles

This might be easy but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I'm using setCustomTitle for my alert dialog in order to use my own view for the dialog title:

```
View customTitle = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_title, null);
new AlertDialog.Builder(AddBusActivity.this).setCustomTitle(customTitle).(some more stuff).show();
```

And dialog_title.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView android:text="My Title"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical">
  </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is making the title `TextView` use the default dialog title style.
In my device the alert dialog background is dark, so text has to be bright, but in other devices it might be different.

I tried adding ***android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle"*** to the TextView, but it caused the text to be black which isn't the right style.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with styles and colors, but resolved it by using custom Dialog instead of AlertDialog.

1) my code with

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setTitle(mName);
...
mDialog = builder.create();
mDialog.show();
```

was changed to

```
dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom_title);
// initializing Views 
dialog.show();
```

2) in layout.dialog_custom_title set needed styles (background and color)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns: android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/dialogs_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >
...
<TextView
...
android:textColor="@color/TxtLightBlue" 
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_default"
/>
...
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code below whiuch set the colors and the spacing quite well

```
 <TextView android:text="My Title"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
</TextView>
```